# Levels Map terminology

Tags: maps, levels, terminology

I wonder if this thing exists and how is it called?

What I mean is not "level editor", but a kind of cover map, where you select, which level you want to play and your character symbol moves to the place accordingly. An example of such a map is here:

[image]

or this one: [image]

Here all you have is a basis image, levels, represented by some image or animation, a character, that is being moved from one position to another and so on.

I'd like to know how this concept is called? I google all the things that pop up into my mind, but none of them is correct.

Comment: As far as I know, this is completely implemented by the game studio that made these games. There is no standard technology (btw, questions requesting technologies are off-topic here because they are very discussion-based) for this reason. You will have to implement this yourself.

Comment: The concept is usually called an overworld

Comment: I'd agree with @Peethor that I usually see this called an overworld map or overworld menu (to distinguish the fact that you select areas with a cursor rather than by navigating an avatar through the landscape as in many older JRPGs). Peethor, would you consider adding that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept is usually referred to as an "overworld".
Bear in mind that the term "overworld", as DMGregory mentioned, could refer to two concepts.

The screenshots you show fall in the category **overworld menu**.
In this category, there's pretty much just a background with multiple icons you can click, resembling levels.

A concept that can easily be confused with this is the **overworld map**, which consists of a map the player can actually walk around on, like in older JRPGs. Take for instance Final Fantasy IV:
[image: Overworld]
In this concept, players walk across a map, and come across cities, dungeons, etc. When entering such a point of interest, the city map or dungeon map loads, creating the feeling of seamless gameplay (while there is obviously a seam).

I just want to mention that these two concepts are not exactly black and white. There have been games in the past that show it's perfectly possible to meet in the middle. Take a look at mario 3:
[image: Mario Map]